# jQuery on click event logic

Tags: jquery, html, events

I'm slowly converting this code to jQuery that I found on w3schools and adding some of my own animations, but I can't figure out where the animation can be triggered.

Perhaps my call to animation is in the wrong spot? I'm trying to play the animation every time you click a new button.

I commented out the call to the animate function because it doesn't work when clicking on other buttons.

```js
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = $(".filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) 
      AddClass(x[i], "show"); 
      //animate();
  }
}

function animate() {
  $('.filterDiv').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
}

function AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn-navi");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.filterDiv {
  float:left;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn-navi {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ed1b2d;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-navi:hover {
  background-color: #ed1b2d;
  border: 1px solid #ed1b2d;
  color: white;
}

.btn-navi.active {
  border: 1px solid #ed1b2d;
  background-color: #ed1b2d;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn-navi active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn-navi" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn-navi" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn-navi" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn-navi" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Red</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cat</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Dog</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Melon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Banana</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Lemon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cow</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time. Since there isn't really a valid question here about the animation, you're just going to get answers about `c = ""`.

Comment: OK, now there's no question anywhere. What is this supposed to do, what is it doing instead?

Comment: Don't comment out the part of the code that's giving you a problem.

Comment: You could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `RemoveClass` and `AddClass` function with your custom animation function and pass the element and the fading value `0` to hide and any other value greater than 0 to show the effect.

Update the animate function to

```
function animateIt(obj, fadeTo) {
  if (fadeTo == 0) {
    return $(obj).css('display', 'none');
  }
  $(obj).fadeTo('slow', fadeTo);
}
```

See a demo below

```js
filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = $(".filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    animateIt(x[i], 0);
    //RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1)
      animateIt(x[i], 0.5);
    //AddClass(x[i], "show"); 

  }
}

function animateIt(obj, fadeTo) {
  if (fadeTo == 0) {
    return $(obj).css('display', 'none');
  }
  $(obj).fadeTo('slow', fadeTo);
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn-navi");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn-navi {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ed1b2d;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-navi:hover {
  background-color: #ed1b2d;
  border: 1px solid #ed1b2d;
  color: white;
}

.btn-navi.active {
  border: 1px solid #ed1b2d;
  background-color: #ed1b2d;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="myBtnContainer">
    <button class="btn-navi active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
    <button class="btn-navi" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
    <button class="btn-navi" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
    <button class="btn-navi" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
    <button class="btn-navi" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
    <div class="filterDiv colors fruits">Orange</div>
    <div class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</div>
    <div class="filterDiv colors">Red</div>
    <div class="filterDiv cars animals">Mustang</div>
    <div class="filterDiv colors">Blue</div>
    <div class="filterDiv animals">Cat</div>
    <div class="filterDiv animals">Dog</div>
    <div class="filterDiv fruits">Melon</div>
    <div class="filterDiv fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
    <div class="filterDiv fruits">Banana</div>
    <div class="filterDiv fruits">Lemon</div>
    <div class="filterDiv animals">Cow</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only other place where `c` is used is the line

```
if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1)
```

If the value of c is "all", this if should always be entered, and using `indexOf("")` will always return a positive number, so it ensure the if is always entered.

It could be removed if you had by example

```
if ((x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) || c == "all")
```

Comment: He's removed this part of the question.

Comment: Thanks Liora, I've removed that part of the questions since there were two parts to this question. My actual question is about the animation, but this helped me thank you.

Comment: Ah xD I didn't see you removed it, sorry.